# getimagesize() warning - filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, image, file, upload

I've got a formular in which users should upload an image with a specific dimension and type.
When I select an image and click on the submit button, a warning comes up:

> Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in xxx.php on line 5

The code to check dimensions and type isn't necassary for this issue.

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["name"]);       
    } else { ?>

    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>             
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]` instead of `$_FILES["image"]["name"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the tmp file in there, not the file name;

```
 list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the block below, you should not be checking for just `$_POST`, but also for the presence of `$_FILES`.  It seems like you aren't successfully sending your file to the server.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);       

}
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out by other answers, you should also be using "tmp_name" instead of name.